# Get File Path From File in Auto-Saved ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a saved listBox. When someone exits the program, it will save all the names in the listBox and when they enter it will add all them back.

The thing is, when the form is opened and listBox2 is empty, it is fine and does its functions. But when the program loads items from the textbox into listBox2 automatically on Form_Load, I get the following error when I click on listBox2.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

on string `fullFileName = selectedFiles[listBox2.SelectedIndex];`

```
private void materialFlatButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL Files|*.dll";
            OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Dll File";
            if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // put the selected result in the global variable
                fullFileName = new List<String>(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames);


                foreach (string s in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s));
                    selectedFiles.Add(s);
                }

            }
        }

List<string> selectedFiles = new List<string>();
        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                string fullFileName = selectedFiles[listBox2.SelectedIndex];
                textBox4.Text = fullFileName;
            }
            else
            {

            }




string path = @"C:\Save.txt";

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {

                        FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
                        fs.Close();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
                        string line = string.Empty;
                        try
                        {
                            //Read the first line of text
                            line = sr.ReadLine();
                            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
                            while (line != null)
                            {
                                this.listBox2.Items.Add(line);
                                //Read the next line
                                line = sr.ReadLine();
                            }

                            //close the file
                            sr.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            //close the file
                            sr.Close();
                        }




                            textBox3.Visible = false;
                            string text = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Add the code from Form_Load to the question.

Comment: I added the Form_Load code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a big flaw, you have a `ListBox` with the file names, and a `List<string>` with the paths but you are saving only the data on the `ListBox`, so when you restore the content of the `ListBox` your `List<string>` remains empty, that's why it gives you an exception on the `SelectedIndexChanged`.

You need to store somehow the paths also and then restore it on load. The most simple solution can be to interleave the data on the file, save a file name from the listbox, a path from the list and so on until you saved everything, then when you read back it you restore a line for the listbox with the name and a line for the list with the path.

EDIT: Better, instead of saving the content from the `ListBox` save the content from the `List<string>` then you can do:

```
line = sr.ReadLine();
//Continue to read until you reach end of file
while (line != null)
{
    this.listBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(line));
    selectedFiles.Add(line);
    //Read the next line
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}

//close the file
sr.Close();
```

Comment: A HUGE thanks for that fix. I see now why it did that!

Comment: Thing is though. That when on reload, that may stop the error, but that does not display the path anymore in textBox4 when I load back in.

Comment: Check if the file has been correctly saved and read (check selectedFiles and listBox2 contents)

Comment: On the FormClosing, it only saves the names in ListBox2 and writes the file. Thus the textfile does not have the path, but only the file names. Any recommended fix?

Comment: Have you read the edit? Save the contents from the List, not the ListBox and then use the code I added.

Comment: I understand! Thanks so much for your time. I edited the save and now it works